# What does an "interface extends interface" relationship look like in UML?

Tags: interface, uml

In Java it's perfectly legal for an interface to extend an interface. Does this relationship in UML look like an "extends" relationship (solid line, closed, unfilled arrowhead) or an "implements" relationship (dotted line, close, unfilled arrowhead)? I can't seem to find an example of this relationship either online or in Fowler's book.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use "extends" (solid line, closed, unfilled arrowhead), which is consistent with how Java uses the `extends` and `implements` keywords.

- **"extends"** == **UML generalization / specialization relationship**
- **"implements"** == **UML realization relationship**

The sub-interface is a specialization of the super-interface, not a realization of it.

See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29224&seqNum=2

[image: Example of interfaces extending interfaces].

Comment: hehe, what a beatiful diamond:)

Comment: @Gabriel - *heh* - it is a nice diagram.  I wish I could take credit for it, but its from the referenced article, so credit to Stephen R. Palmer.

Comment: @Bert F I was trying to hint at the diamond inheritance problem:)

Comment: @Gabriel - lol - I'm dense.  Doesn't apply to Java interfaces though, right?

Comment: @Bert F I was not sure myself, according to this:
<a href="http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html">9.3.2.1 Ambiguous Inherited Fields</a> it is a problem, which at least gets resolved at compile time. But I have no idea if this holds for methods.

Comment: @Gabriel - very interesting!  I wasn't aware of that issue.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Regarding the (or a cousin of) diamond problem, if interface A contains method `void someMethod()` and interface B contains method `String someMethod()` then a *uh-oh moment* triggers. Note that the problem is the return type; if the return type is also the same then all is well.